# jquery ajax question marks in output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, encoding

I have three files.

index.php => output from javascript.js goes here.

javascript.js => contains ajax post request for php file to grab some data from database.

ajax.php => basically grabbing data from database and returning it to javascript.js

Once everything is running properly with no special characters in database, the problem appears when they are there. Instead of this special character like 'à' => question marks appear.

I'm using PDO with set names utf8, in database everything is in utf8_general_ci, when I'm trying to test data incomming for ajax.php file everything is fine. The problem appears once sending data back from ajax.php file to javascript.js file, and now when i'm alert() data, there are question marks instead of special characters.

I was googling it for hours, but I didnt find any solution for my problem. What should I do, what should I change? Files are encoded also with utf8. Utf8 meta tag is also included.

Ajax.php

```
if (isset($_POST['cat_id'])) {
    $cat_id = (int) $_POST['cat_id'];
    if ($cat_id == 0) { $cat_id = 1; }
    $data = $system->grabSubcategories($cat_id, true);

    $final_output = '';


    if ($system->getLanguage() == 'en') {
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $final_output .= '<option value="'. $item->id .'">'. strtolower($item->name) .'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $final_output .= '<option value="'. $item->id .'">'. strtolower($item->name_fr) .'</option>';
        }
    }

    echo $final_output;
}
```

javascript.js

```
function chooseCategory() {
    var cat_id = $('#placead_category').val();

    $('#placead_subcategory').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
        data: { cat_id:cat_id },
        success:function(data){
            $('#placead_subcategory').append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

index.php has on its begin:

```
<!-- Include Meta -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/>
        <meta name="author" content="some author..."/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>some title...</title>
        <link rel="Shortcut icon" href="" />
        <!-- /Include Meta -->
```

Comment: uhm, can you post your code? specifically, is the html meta tag "charset" present and set to utf-8 in your index.php?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio post is edited.

Comment: thanks. it looks ok, what about the html "head" portion of your index.php? do you have the charset meta? ( something like <meta charset="UTF-8"> )

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio yeah, edited also

Comment: It really looks fine... Can I suggest you to base64 encode your data before sending it via ajax? When you decode it from php, it shouldn't show any question-mark-broken-encoding-character.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio i encoded output from ajax.php to base64 and then decode it within javascript.js file, result is like question marks disappears but i have characters like ' ã¹ ' instaed of ' é '

Comment: well, that's disturbing... in Ajax.php, right after $data = $system->grabSubcategories($cat_id, true);   can you please var_dump($data) ?